# Filtering records according to dropdownlist

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I need to filter the listing or records according to selection in dropdownlists.
I have three dropdowns that needs to filter the records reactively in collaboration with each other. i.e value selection in one dropdownlist should filter the records effected by other dropdownlist values.

```
var filterAndLimitResults = function (cursor) {

    if (!cursor) {
        return [];
    }

    var raw = cursor.fetch();

    var currentChosenCategory = chosenCategory.get();
    var currentChosenCity = chosenCity.get();
    var currentJtype = chosenJtype.get();

    console.log(currentChosenCategory);
    console.log(currentChosenCity);
    // filter category
    var filtered = [];
    if (!currentChosenCategory || currentChosenCategory == "" && !currentChosenCity || currentChosenCity == "" && !currentJtype || currentJtype == "")
    {
        filtered = raw;
      //  console.log(filtered);
    }
    else {

        filtered = _.filter(raw, function (item) {
          if(currentChosenCategory){
            return item.ccategory === currentChosenCategory ;
          }
          if(currentChosenCity){
            return item.city === currentChosenCity ;
            console.log(item.city === currentChosenCity);
          }
        });
      }

var currentLimit =limit.get();
//enforce the limit
if (currentLimit ) {
    filtered = _.first(filtered, currentLimit );
}
return filtered;
};
```

the above code is doing both filtering the dropdowns and limit the number of records so as to give infinite scrolling.

**Edit For Text Based Search**

Here is my eventmap for seach box

```
"keyup #search-title":function(e,t){
     if(e.which === 27){
       searchTitle.set("");
     }
     else {
       var text = $(e.target.val);
       searchTitle.set(text)
       console.log(searchTitle.set(text));
     }
   }
```

This is what iam doing in the `filteredAndLimitResults`

```
if(!(!currentSearchTitle || currentSearchTitle == "")) {
      filtered = _.filter(filtered, function (item) {
              return item.title === currentSearchTitle ;
              console.log(item.title === currentSearchTitle);
      });
    }
```

when i am typing something in the search box. all the records vanishes and when in press `esc` it comes back to as it was. in `console.log` i can see that on everytime i press a key it returns the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enforce the filters one after the other. Try like that:

```
var filterAndLimitResults = function (cursor) {

    if (!cursor) {
        return [];
    }

    var raw = cursor.fetch();

    var currentChosenCategory = chosenCategory.get();
    var currentChosenCity = chosenCity.get();
    var currentJtype = chosenJtype.get();

    console.log(currentChosenCategory);
    console.log(currentChosenCity);
    // filter category
    var filtered = [];
    if (!currentChosenCategory || currentChosenCategory == "" || currentChosenCategory === "All categories")
    {
        filtered = raw;
        //  console.log(filtered);
    }
    else {
        filtered = _.filter(raw, function (item) {
            if(currentChosenCategory){
                return item.ccategory === currentChosenCategory ;
            }
        });
    }
    // filter city
    if (!(!currentChosenCity || currentChosenCity == "" || currentChosenCity === "All cities"))
 {
        filtered = _.filter(filtered, function (item) {
            if(currentChosenCity){
                return item.city === currentChosenCity ;
                console.log(item.city === currentChosenCity);
            }
        });
    }
    // filter JType
    if (!(!currentJtype || currentJtype == "" || currentJtype === "All Jtypes"))
 {
        filtered = _.filter(filtered, function (item) {
            if(currentJtype){
                //update the item.ccategory with the right field
                return item.ccategory === currentJtype ;
            }
        });
    }
    var currentLimit =limit.get();
    //enforce the limit
    if (currentLimit ) {
        filtered = _.first(filtered, currentLimit );
    }
    return filtered;
};
```

Comment: is this a typo? `if !(!currentChosenCity || currentChosenCity == "")` that `!` is throwing error. so i made it like this `if (!(!currentChosenCity || currentChosenCity == ""))`. and other thing is i can't see the records now. they are not being displayed

Comment: You are right, I forgot the parenthesis so it should be `if (!(!currentChosenCity || currentChosenCity == ""))`. Try to add a `console.log(filtered);` after each filter.

Comment: its working now thanks.Just another thing i need to add an All Cities,All categories for this in dropdown.so that should be like All ciategories in New york or Marketing in Seattle and the likes. how can i do that in this?

Comment: You can just skip the filtering if your filter value (i.e. `currentChosenCity` matches `All cities`). I edited the answer. You will also need to push into your dropdown items the "All categories" option. You can do it simply by adding it into HTML, before the `{{#each category}}`. That way it will be always displayed.

Comment: Great thanks it is working now. thanks for your efforts in helping me.

Comment: what if i want to add a text based search to this? can i go about the same logic flow for that? offcourse i have to do the `keypress` event for this. but main concern is logic

Comment: Yes you can. You will need to map on the `keyUp` event rather than `keypress` which is deprecated. You also need to handle the `escape` inside the `keyUp` to set your string to "".

Comment: Updated my question with the code and the error i am getting.on every keypress its returning the total collection in console but all the records in the template vanishes until i press `esc` it returns back.

Comment: can you please check my updated question and help me in what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Ok. posted a new question for this [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954709/filter-and-search-using-textbox)